# What is the difference between multi node hadoop cluster and running hadoop on mesos?

Tags: hadoop, mesos

I've built a multi node hadoop cluster, then i started studying mesos and the ability to run hadoop on mesos cluster, so here's my questions:

```
1) Should I run hadoop on mesos cluster? or it doesn't matter.
2) What is the difference between them?
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different things in different hierarchies. You could deploy the hadoop cluster in a set of machines directly. So that your machines could handle hadoop jobs now.

Or you could deploy mesos cluster first, and then deploy hadoop cluster, spark cluster, kafka and other things on mesos. So that you could sumbit your hadoop jobs to the hadoop cluster, submit your spark jobs to the spark cluster.

[image: mesos hierarchies]